# sending variable value to Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just learning about bootstrap..I need help from anyone who know how to send variable value to a modal..

to make it even clearer, I have a table with action column. the action column consist of edit and delete button. if the edit button clicked, then a modal with edit form appear ( I put the modal in the same file with the modal trigger button). my question is, how do I send the ID of the following data to the edit form in the modal???

here is the code of edit(update) data:

```
<a data-target="#modal-edit-user" data-toggle="modal"> <i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-edit">
```

and here is the modal code:

```
<div id="modal-edit-user" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><b>Form Edit Data User</b></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form name="tambah_user" method="POST" action="../controller/edit_user.php">
              <?php echo $id_user;?>
              <div class="controls control-group">  
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nama_user" placeholder=" nama user">
                <br><input class="form-control" type="text" name="alamat" placeholder=" alamat user">
                <br><input class="form-control" type="text" name="kota" placeholder=" kota">
                <br><input class="form-control" type="text" name="no_telp" placeholder=" nomor telepon user">
                <br><input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder=" username login user">
                <br><input class="form-control" type="text" name="password" placeholder="password login user">
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</a>
                <input type="submit" name="sumbit" value="Simpan" class="btn btn-primary">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I hope there is someone who can explain me the answer.. thanks a lot :-)

Comment: You should use javascript, since PHP is server-side language only.

Comment: can you give me example to make it easier for me to understand?
@intelis

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Javascript. Just add a click event listener and update the form, when edit button is clicked. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.user-edit').click(function () {
        $('span.user-id').text($(this).data('id'));
    });

});
```

Here is a quick **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ts25J/2/)** of how you could go about it.

Comment: Wow Thanks... your code works!
I Hope I could return the favor someday... 
Thank you very much @intelis

Comment: if an answer was helpful you can submit it as an accepted answer :)